# Python/Calling python scripts within bash terminal: What exactly happens when user presses Ctrl-C?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ctrl

I need help with controlling a python script. I want to run a script that controls two robots. A routine consists of a series of motions which either move the arm or move the gripper. The form of the code is as follows:

```
def robot_exec():
  # List of robot arm poses:
  *many_many_lines_of_position_vectors*

  # List of robot gripper poses:
  *open position*
  *close position*

  while 1:
    *Call a function that moves the robot arm(s) to a position on the list*
    *Call a function that moves the robot gripper(s) to a position on the list*
    *continue calling functions many times until the desired routine is complete*
    n = raw_input("Restart the routine? (Y/N)")
    if n.strip() == 'n' or 'N':
      break
    elif n.strip() == 'y' or 'Y':
      continue
    else:
      print "Invalid input. Exiting..."
      break
```

If the routine is complete (i.e. every function was called), it asks if I want to restart, and if I choose yes, behaves as normal, which is good.

But, if I press ctrl-C in the middle of the routine, the message "Restart the routine?" still pops up and asks for input, and I don't want that. What I want is either one of the following:

1. if and only if the user presses ctrl-C, completely exit everything, no questions asked.
2. if and only if the user presses ctrl-C, return the robots to home position (defined in that list of arm poses) and then completely exit everything.

My main question is, how does ctrl-C actually work? I thought it would just exit the script but in actuality it still prints stuff and asks for input. A subset of that broad question is, how can I just get the desired behavior (completely exit everything when pressing ctrl-C)?

I realize this is a clunky way of doing what I need the robots to do, but it is the best way I can think of with my limited knowledge of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments/answers about signals are technically correct (on UNIX), but in Python the CTRL+C handling is neatly wrapped away from you. What happens in a Python program is that at the point where you press CTRL+C, a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is raised.

Now, your problem seems to be in the code that you have removed from the listing, i.e., in the "calling robot routines" part. That code catches the `KeyboardInterrupt`.

I guess either your code or library code that you call does something like:

```
try:
    # some long running code
    # ...
except:
    # something, or just pass
```

Note the naked `except:`. Naked `except`s are almost always a bad thing. Instead you or the library should do:

```
try:
    # some long running code
    # ...
except Exception:
    # something to fix the situation
```

Using `except Exception:` does not catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, which will let you handle it appropriately, or just let the program exit. Have a look at the [Exception class hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly happens when user presses Ctrl-C?

A signal is raised.

---

> how can I just get the desired behavior

```
>>> import signal
>>> def handler(sig, stack_frame):
...     print "Handled"
... 
>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
<built-in function default_int_handler>
^C   # <--- typed ctrl-c here
>>> Handled
```

See the doc of [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) for details.

---

Please note: on Linux I use `signal.SIGINT`. On Windows, maybe it is `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle `Ctrl_C` with this code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        #write your command here for example i write print below :
        print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print('Press Ctrl+C')
signal.pause()
```